# How to reset a form to pristine after submitted in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I haven't the toughest time resetting this form to pristine once the reset/send button is clicked!  I have tried the angular.copy method, $scope.contactForm.$setPristine();  to no avail. I was getting an error stating that $scope.contactForm.$setPristine(); was undefined. Do anyone see a problem in my code!

Here is my HTML

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM -->
<div class="sixteen columns contact-container">
    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <p class="required">* = Required</p>

    <div id="messages" data-ng-show="message">{{message}}</div>

    <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" class="contact" method="post" novalidate>

        <label ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.name.$invalid && !contactForm.name.$pristine }">Name*
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" data-ng-model="userData.name" placeholder="Joe Blow" required>
            <p data-ng-show="contactForm.name.$invalid && !contactForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </label>

        <label ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.email.$invalid && !contactForm.email.$pristine }">eMail*
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" data-ng-model="userData.email" placeholder="joe84@email.com"     required>
            <p data-ng-show="contactForm.email.$invalid && !contactForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">You email is required.    </p>
        </label>

        <label ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.comment.$invalid && !contactForm.comment.$pristine }">Comment*
            <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" ng-model="userData.comments" required></textarea>
            <p data-ng-show="contactForm.comment.$invalid && !contactForm.comment.$pristine" class="help-block">You comment is     required.</p>
        </label>

        <p>
            <button data-ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="processForm()">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- END: CONTACT FORM -->
```

Here is my controller

```
 // 'use strict';
/* Controllers */
var myAppControllers = angular.module('myAppControllers', ['myServices']);

myAppControllers.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http, $compile) {
        console.log('contactCtrl');

        // Empty object to hold input info
        $scope.userData = {};

        // Process Form
        $scope.processForm = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'send-mail.php',
                data: $.param($scope.userData),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            })
                .success(function () {
                    $scope.userData = {};
                    alert('Message Sent');
                });
        }

        $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.userData = {};
            console.log('Reset Clicked');
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I ran into `$setPristine` problems today as well. Not sure if this will help, but does changing your `<form>` to `<ng-form>` make a difference? The form controller seems finicky as the problem I faced was placing `<ng-form>` between a bootstrapped `<accordion>` seemed to disable the FormController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though this is an old question, as none of the answers thus far provide a working solution, I thought it would be helpful to do so to benefit others who might have the same question. ( After all, that's why I landed here :-)

As a couple answers have indicated, in order to set a form back to Angular's notion of pristine you **must** call `$setPristine()` on the form:

```
$scope.contactForm.$setPristine();
```

You must *also* clear the model so that angular binding will update each form field *either* to empty or, as is the case with the OP here, to its *cue banner* (also known as watermark text, ghost text, or placeholder text):

```
$scope.userData = {};
```

By setting the model to an empty object, then any of its properties accessed in HTML (e.g. `userData.name` or `userData.email` here) will be undefined and trigger the empty/cue banner rendering.

Comment: Still, $scope.contactForm might be undefined due to directive child scope in template. It would be better to pass the form from the ng-click `ng-click="resetForm(contactForm)"`. It is always better when you don't read data from scope in controller. That was probably also the problem in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion:

1) Add ng-submit to the form to process the results, rather than ng-click on a button

2) change the button for reset to an input of type reset with no ng-click (try that first, if it works like I expect, it will blank all the values and that will update the model, and everything will work the way you want) - if not you can revisit the ng-click method

Comment: I tried your suggestion and wasn't able to clear the input back to $pristine!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$scope.contactForm.$setPristine();
$scope.model = '';
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail why you suggest this? It's not much of an answer otherwise.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your form like this

```
$scope.reset = function () {
  $scope.userData = {};
  document.getElementById("contactForm").reset();
}
```

Calling reset on a form goes back to pristine state.

Comment: This only wipes form data and does not set Angular form to pristine state. That what is $setPristine() method in form controller for.

Comment: please, never access DOM from controller. Also, don't use `document`, use `$document`